# is there a way to get the DOM object given a $$hashKey?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<table>` where each row has a couple of `input type="text"`. I want to validate if an input is empty and if so, then add a CSS class to this input field which will display an error. All I got in the `$scope` is the `$$hashKey`, I know this is an unique value to identify an element of a `ng-repeat` list.

How could I get the DOM object given this `$$hashKey`?. I was digging using the Developer Tools but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the DOM (ie find and element and add/remove a class) from your controller (or service), you should be doing it from a directive.

Write a directive that will do the validation for you:

```
.directive('validateField', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal){
                var isValid = false;
                // do some validation checking on newVal here
                ngModel.$setValidity('tableInput', isValid);
            });

        }
    };
 });
```

As noted in the docs [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController), the `$setValidity` function will automatically add a class to the element for you, based on whatever key you provide.  In this case, we provided a key of `'tableInput'` so it will add a class of `ng-invalid-table-input` when the model is invalid, and a class of `ng-valid-table-input` when the model is valid.

So in your CSS, all you now have to do is create a rule with some special styles:

```
input.ng-invalid-table-input{
    /* special styles go here */
}
input.ng-valid-table-input{
    /* special styles go here */
}
```

And then you would use this in your view as such:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="things in listOfThings">
        <td ng-repeat="thing in things">
            <input type="text" ng-model="someValue" validate-field />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then any input in your table will be dynamically (and automatically) validated and styled.  Does that make sense?  You'd have to modify the above example, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks neat, but it looks like  $setValidity is not available for stable version so far. Could I add/remove the class by myself from the directive?

Comment: The current "stable" version of angular is 1.0.8.  Here's the docs for `$setValidity()` for 1.0.8: http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController.  So you can still use it in the "stable" build.